# Passing AJAX variable into .php page and load that page and echo variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Simple question: 
I just want to send `item_num` to insert_profile.php, then load insert_profile.php and echo out `item_num` there. It's not working! 'insert_profile.php' will load but it's not getting the data.

Is it a problem with my `data:`? I've also tried `data: {item_num: item_num}`. I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've tried all of the examples I've seen and none of them are working. I think it could also be in `success:`

I've also looked at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

**Javascript/HTML**

```
 <script>

$('.prof_wl_btn').click(function() { 
$(this).removeClass('prof_wl_btn');
$(this).addClass('prof_wl_btn_added');
  var item_num = this.id;
  alert('item id    ' + item_num); //*this will alert correctly*
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:'insert_profile.php',
      data: "item_num"+item_num,   
      success: location.href = "insert_profile.php" //*this will load**   
  });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$s_n = $_REQUEST['item_num'];
echo $s_n;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't echo the variable this way because you have two different requests for the same page:

- The first is the AJAX request when you send the data to your page where you do some action and the return;
- The second one when you access `insert_profile.php` page, when your value is lost.

If you want to see that your value is echoed you can do this:

The AJAX call should look like:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:'insert_profile.php',
      data: {item_num : item_num},   
      success : function(data) {
         alert(data);  
      }
  });
```

Then your PHP file:

```
<?php $s_n = $_POST['item_num']; 
  echo $s_n;
  exit;
?>
```

Comment: so could I put it into a `$_SESSION` variable? Or what can I do?

Comment: Yes, you can put it on a session variable.

Comment: the above code will echo correctly, but how could I have the data be echoed out from `insert_profile.php`? I tried putting into a `$_SESSION` variable, but it doesn't work. I tried `$_SESSION['var'] = $s_n;
 echo $_SESSION['var'];` Do I have to put it into the `SESSION` and then do another re-direct from there?

Comment: where do you need to echo it? on the same page where you make the AJAX request or when you go to page `insert_profile.php`? Anyway if you have a file you use for AJAX requests is good to use it only for AJAX requests, not to access it  directly.

Comment: I'd like it to echo from `insert_profile.php` after the AJAX sends redirects the browser. I tried putting it into the `SESSION` but it still lost it I believe, b/c when it echoes the variable it is blank.

Comment: use another file for the redirect, you are doing same thing twice (AJAX request and then redirect on same page and this can have different behaviors)...

Comment: anyway you can do this: your php file should look like `session_start();
  if($_POST)
  {
   $s_n = $_POST['item_num'];
   $_SESSION['var'] = $s_n;
  }
  else
  {
   echo $_SESSION['var'];
  }`

Comment: that's it! The `if/else` statement clears up what's going on and how the ajax is performing. Thanks, +584 internets to you!

Comment: after further implementation I've discovered another problem arise. There are multiple instances of each button that is clicked to trigger the `<script>`. Each button has a different "`item_num`", so can't use the `if/else` statement. It needs to over-write anything that's already there, if that makes sense. I'll see what I can do. If anyone reads this and has an idea, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:'insert_profile.php',
      data: "item_num = "+item_num,   
      success : function( data ) {
         // location.href = "insert_profile.php" //*this will load** 
         alert(data);  
      }
  });
```

In PHP code you do like this and check

```
<?php
echo 'OK';
```

Comment: @user2118228 you are missing `=` in `data: "item_num"+item_num` and success should be a function.

Comment: Or in shorthand notation you could use `$.post("insert_profile.php", {"item_num" : item_num}, function(){location.href = "insert_profile.php"})`

Comment: I added the `=` in, it's still not echoing the variable.

Comment: @user2118228 Check my updated answer and try this. And check what should alert.

Comment: I don't know `PHP` much, but shouldn't the PHP code have `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: with this it is alerting: OK

Comment: @user2118228 now use your code `$s_n = $_POST['item_num']; echo $s_n;` then check alert

Comment: @som now the alert is coming up blank! what does this mean?

Comment: @user2118228 let me know `alert('item id ' + item_num);` and `alert(data);` are same output

Comment: `alert('item id ' + item_num);` will alert the correct information.
`alert(data);` alerts nothing.